# Authorising cross site web app to access my RESTful API

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

Here is the scenario:

I have a web app with some RESTful APIs, the users are using an IdP to do SSO. I registered my web app (as well as many others 3rd party web apps) to the IdP and when the users want to use my web app, I will redirect users to the login page of the IdP and do normal SAML 2 stuff to authenticate the user. This part has been done already. Now once logged in, users can freely use any web app registered to the IdP. The next to do is to authorise some of these web apps (not all) to be able to use my RESTful APIs.

Different from the normal OAuth 2 granting flow, it is not the users allowing their 3rd party web apps to use my APIs, instead, I want to control which 3rd party web apps can use my APIs. Something like the user will request from me to grant a certain web app of his/hers to use which of my APIs. Or any other good suggestions I am all ears.

Comment: Can you just set those guys up in your CORS?

Comment: are you sure, you gonna follow that route? apps will access api direct and too customize for different apps to different users?

Comment: @geminiousgoel Yes, based on the role of the user (since my web app is allowed to query their IdP for this information) and my whitelist of 3rd party web apps, I will have some automated rules to deny or grant access to my APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this [spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-campbell-oauth-resource-indicators-02), which provides more control of the distributed access tokens.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean what I am after has no standard yet?